# UISearchBar And UISearchBarTextField heigh on different IOS versions

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, ios13, ios10.3

I have used  a UISearchbar in a controller. When I test it in IOS 13 UISearchBar height is 56 and UISearchBarTextField heigh is 36 but When I test in IOS 10.3 UISearchBar heght is 44 and TextField height is 28. I want to make it same in all versions.How can I do it?

[image]

IOS 10.3 preview

[image]

IOS 13 preview

Answer (score 0):

If you want same height in all devices then fix height constraint to UISearchBar